# Flutter debug error "Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

When trying to debug my Flutter app on Android emulator I am getting the following error:

```
Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under <project_folder>\app\build, but the tool couldn't find it.
```

I have been crawling through StackOverflow and GitHub to get to the root cause but could not find anything that works.

I have seen in many posts that this behaviour might be due to a unspecified app flavor when running debug but I am not defining any flavor at all.

I tried to create a brand new project and pasting my code back into lib folder but nothing changed.

Command `flutter build appbundle` fails as well so when I want to produce an app bundle I have to do it through Android Studio (I code using VS Code).

The only way I can get this app to work on debug mode is by switching back to `flutter version 1.9.1+hotfix.6` which is pretty annoying since I have another app that works fine and I have to develop using latest version.

This is my `app/build.gradle` file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        resConfigs "es"
    }

    signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
       }
   }

    buildTypes {
        release {
           signingConfig signingConfigs.release
           minifyEnabled true
           shrinkResources true
           useProguard true

           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
       }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:5.15.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

and this is my `gradle-wrapper.properties` file in case that matters

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are some things that *might* help you or future viewers:

1. Run `flutter clean` which is equal to deleting the `build` folder
2. Double check your `.vscode\launch.json` for extra arguments.
3. Check your IDE's debug and build setup.
4. Inspect your `android\app\build.gradle`. I know you mentioned that you don't use flavors, but when moving to a new dev environment, some setups can be overwhelming!
5. Probably too late to help with your question, but try creating a new Flutter project and start moving the custom parts of your `android` root folder.

Happy coding! :)

Comment: `flutter clean; flutter pub get` That was it! Thank you man

Answer (score 0):

For those who don't use flavors, this is how I fixed it.

1. Navigate to your root project directory
2. Then run: `flutter create.` (notes the dot(.) at the end of the command
3. There will be two MainActivity files created. One for kotlin and other one for native java. Navigate to one of the MainActivity class which you're not using and comment MyActivity class so as to remove the duplicate error.
4. Run in your terminal: `flutter clean`
5. Then run `flutter pub get`
6. You can now run your app using `flutter run` or using the IDE Run button.